# Copy image classes to wrapping div container in Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

i would like to wrap a div-container around a image in Wordpress.

This is what i have:

```
<div class="image-container">

   <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-24" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/header01.jpg" alt="" width="512" height="512" />

</div>
```

This is what i want:

```
<div class="image-container alignleft size-full">

   <img class="" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/header01.jpg" alt="" width="512" height="512" />

</div>
```

I want to copy the classes of the image into the container and delete the classes of the image.

I know I can delete the classes of the image, like that:

```
add_filter('get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string');
```

But how do I get the classes in the container?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
function wrap_my_div($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size){
    preg_match('/class="(.*)?"/', $html, $alignment);
    $html = preg_replace('/class="(.*)?"/', '', $html);
    $html = '<div class="image-container '. $alignment[1] .'">' . $html . '</div>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'wrap_my_div', 10, 4);
```

I have to take a look at the RegEx.